# Errors and CRUD checks not working in NetworkMember Trigger for users with Community license

Tags: apex, trigger, community

I am noticing an interesting behavior with the trigger on NetworkMember object wherein on forcing an error it does not block the transaction.

**Use case:** As a security best practice I was trying to put checks to see if any user with a Customer Community Login profile has CRUD access to a custom object before inserting records on it. This logic depends on the reputation points that Community user gains based on the interaction in the Community. Since the reputation points are stored on the NetworkMember object I have set up the trigger on the NetworkMember object, so that on the change of reputation points my custom code to insert a record on the custom object triggers. This logic works fine and I have no issues.

But now when I add CRUD check to ensure that only on Create access the logic should run, it runs successfully even when Customer Community Login profile does not have to create access.

Code I use to check the CRUD permission on the object is : `Schema.sObjectType.Custom_Object__c.isCreateable()`

In order to check if this code even gets executed and what is the value returned, I forced an error to happen by putting a false assertion. But there is no error logged in the debug logs nor the user posting the question in the community is getting errors back. Reputation points are successfully updated on the NetworkMember object

```
System.assert(false, UserInfo.getName() + ' ' + Schema.sObjectType.Custom_Object__c.isCreateable());
```

Also, I tried to force a divide by zero error and it was not captured.

```
trigger NetworkMemberTrigger on NetworkMember (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after the update, after delete, after undelete) {
        Integer i = 1/0;
}
```

Note: The above scenarios happen only when the running user is an external Community member with a Customer Community Login profile. For users with a full Salesforce license, this is not an issue.

Hence I was confused

1. Why a forced error is not logged in debug logs for NetworkMember trigger.
2. Why checking CRUD access not working in the context of the NetworkMember object.

Comment: Do you enable logs as community user.or regular user? Note that trigger logic executes in system context unless you call a helper class from the trigger context

Comment: Hi Mohit, Debug logs are enabled on the Community user. I also added the system. assert and also the divide by zero code in the helper class and was getting the same behavior as having the code directly in the trigger.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me that you would want to report by raising a support case!

Comment: ok, reaching out to Salesforce support to check on this.